# how to make an expected error in react js using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here I'm trying to simulate an expected error 404 to test the code but it always shows the unexpected message which is 'unexpected error occurred.' 
what am I doing wrong here???

```
handleDelete = async (post) => {
    const originalPosts = this.state.posts;

    const posts = this.state.posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id);
    this.setState({ posts });

    try {
      await axios.delete(apiEndpoin + '/999');
    } catch (ex) {
      if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404)
        alert('This post has already been deleted.');
      else alert('unexpeted error occurred.');
      this.setState({ posts: originalPosts });
    }
  };
```

Comment: what does `console.log(ex)` give you underneath the `catch(ex)` line?

Comment: that's what it gives I guess I'm simulating the 404 error in a wrong way, am I?
     Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/999' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: So you need to enable cors on the server then

Comment: I'm using a fake backend 'jsonplaceholder'